# Avoid beep on pressing enter in numeric up down dialog

Tags: c#, dialog

I have some numeric up/down controls in a c# application.  Whenever I press enter on one of these, the computer sounds a beep.  How do I prevent this from happening?

This seems to be a common problem, but I'm unable to find an answer that is complete enough for me to be able to make it work.  Pehrhaps a stackoverflow quality answer would be useful.

Comment: The Enter key is reserved to close the dialog.  Set the form's AcceptButton property.  And the CancelButton property so Escape works properly too.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can just suppress the KeyPress event on the KeyDown event:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't try this.  Hans Passant's comment clued me in as to where I was going wrong, so I just added a dummy button, positioned off the form, and pointed the form's AcceptButton to point at it.